# Gnome-terminal: Difference between -e and --?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to open a terminal that shows a file as it's being written. A progress percentage is written into the file and I'd like the user to see it.

Most solutions I have found for opening a new terminal say to use `-e`, but that returns

```
# Option "-e" is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal
# Use "-- " to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

I've seen discussion about this error, but I'm still unsure as to what the functional difference between `-e` and `--` actually is. Scripts that I run that use `-e` stop working properly if I just swap them, so there's obviously something that I'm missing.

Comment: -e option to ... what? gnome-terminal?

Comment: @glennjackman yes. "e" stands for "execute". See [the manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html).

Comment: @glennjackman yes

Comment: I think it's telling you that if you used to use `gnome-terminal … -e 'command with args to execute' …`, you should now use `gnome-terminal … … -- command with args to execute` instead, because at some time in the next 20 years, the `-e` option will be removed. Note that the `-e` option probably could appear between other control options, hence the two lots of `…` in my outline code. If it had to appear at the end, followed by the command name and options, you shouldn't spot a difference when changing from `-e` to `--`, so I assume that it wasn't like that (but you know what `ass*u*me` does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-e` would take a single argument which would have to be parsed as a shell command, but it could precede other `gnome-terminal` arguments. For example,

```
gnome-terminal -e 'command "argument with spaces"' --some-other-gnome-terminal-option
```

`--` is not itself an option; it's a special argument that signals the *end* of options. Anything following `--` is ignored by `gnome-terminal`'s own option parser and treated like an ordinary argument. Something like

```
gnome-terminal -- 'command "argument with spaces"' --some-other-gnome-terminal-option
```

would present 2 additional arguments to `gnome-terminal` following the `--`:

1. `command "argument with spaces"`
2. `--some-other-gnome-terminal-option`

Further, you would get an error, because `gnome-terminal` would attempt to run a command named `command "argument with spaces"`, rather than a command named `command`.

---

In practice, this means you can't simply replace `-e` with `--` and call it a day. Instead, you would first move `-e` to the *end* of the options list:

```
gnome-terminal --some-other-gnome-terminal-option -e 'command "argument with spaces"'
```

then replace `-e '...'` with `-- ...`. The command and each of its arguments are now distinct arguments to `gnome-terminal`, which removes the need for an entire layer of quoting.

```
gnome-terminal --some-other-gnome-terminal-option -- command "argument with spaces"
```

Comment: ...and if you have been using `-e` to launch different programs in multiple tabs [you are apparently in serious trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764599/opening-new-gnome-terminal-v3-28-with-multiple-tabs-and-different-commands). What an unfortunate deprecation decision.